# Scala: modify field

Tags: scala

Why output is -10?

```
class Person {
        var age: Int = 0
        def age_(newAge: Int) {
                if( newAge > 0 ) age = newAge
        }
}

object Main extends App {
        val p = new Person
        p.age = -10
        println(p.age)
}
```

scalac Main.scala
scala Main
-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to write *setter* but due to the wrong syntax you ended up with a variable visible from the outside AND weirdly named method:

```
val x = new Person()
x.age_(3)
x.age_(-10)

x.age
//  Int = 3
```

Correct way of writing setter could be (note trailing `=` in the method name):

```
class Person {
    private var privateAge: Int = 0

    def age_=(newAge: Int) {
      if( newAge > 0 ) privateAge = newAge
    }

    def age = privateAge
}

val x = new Person()
x: Person = Person@42c08a7e

x.age = -10
// x.age: Int = 0

x.age
// res7: Int = 0
```

Comment: Не думал, что могу так упоротся и не заметить =. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
val p = new Person
p.age = -10
```

You are setting the age value to -10

Comment: I guess answer [lacks this picture](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070106155834/uncyclopedia/images/archive/1/15/20070526081818!CaptainobviousChooseOption.jpg) :-)

Comment: But in class i forbidden negative value: if( newAge > 0 )

Comment: But you are setting it as -10

Comment: p.age = -10 it is not setting field age. It`s call age_=(-10)

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?